# Godot SQLite Foreign Key

Tags: sqlite, godot

Could someone please show me how to create a foreign key relationship between two tables in Godot. I can not figure based on the current documentation.

```
extends Node2D

const SQLite = preload("res://addons/godot-sqlite/bin/gdsqlite.gdns")

var save_path = "user://data.sqlite"
var db 

func _ready():

    
    db = SQLite.new()
    db.path = save_path
    db.foreign_keys = true
    db.open_db()
    
    db.create_table("dog_names", {
        "id": {"data_type": "int", "primary_key": true, "auto_increment": true},
        "first_name": {"data_type": "text"},
        "last_name": {"data_type": "text"},
    })
    
    db.create_table("owners", {
        "id": {"data_type": "int", "primary_key": true, "auto_increment": true}, 
        "name": {"data_type": "text"}
    })
    db.query("SELECT * FROM dog_names;")
    print(db.query_result[0]["first_name"])
```

Essentially I just want to add a many-to-one relationship between table owner and table dog.
One owner can have many dogs but a dog can only have one owner.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to enable them before opening the database:

```
db.foreign_keys = true
# …
db.open_db()
```

Then you need a field that references the other table, and add an entry of the form `"foreign_key": "TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME"` (the `data_type` must match, the referenced field must be either `"primary_key": true` or `"unique": true`):

For example:

```
db.create_table("dog", {
        # …
        "owner_id": {"data_type": "int", "foreign_key": "owner.id"}
    })
```

And that would make your relationship. In this case the dog zero or one owner (you can use `"not_null": true` if you want to enforce it must have one). And the `owner` has zero to many dogs.

---

With the foreign key constraint, when you insert or modify the records of the `dog` table, the `owner_id` field must match one of the `id` of one of the records on the `owner` table (or be `null`).

For example, if the record on the `dog` table says `owner_id` is `123`, then there must be a record on the `owner` table which `id` is `123`. It won't let you insert or modify that value in such way that it violates that constraint.

So that once you have inserted data in your database, you know that you can use the `owner_id` to query into the `owner` table:

```
var dog_query_str := "SELECT owner_id FROM dog;"
var owner_query_str := "SELECT name FROM owner WHERE id=?;"
db.query(dog_query_str)
for result in db.query_result:
    db.query_with_bindings(owner_query_str, [result["owner_id"]])
    print(db.query_result)
```

*Note that here I'm using [prepared statements](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-1-prepared-statements-with-parameterized-queries).*

Or you can use a JOIN:

```
var query_str := "SELECT name FROM dog JOIN owner ON dog.owner_id = owner.id;"
db.query(query_str)
print(db.query_result)
```

You would, of course, modify this to your needs. Please refer to [SQL As Understood By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) for the SQL syntax supported by SQLite.

Comment: Then how do you assign a specific dog to a person?

Comment: @TonyDean You set the field, just like any other field. In the code in the question you create a couple tables and then query, I don't see you insert anything. Edit: to be clear, the idea is they must match. So the dog table says the owner had the id 123, then there must be a person with id 123. It won't let you set that value to the field otherwise. So that you know that you can use the id to query into the other table (or make a join). I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

So is this the best/only way to get information from the `foreign_key` relationship?

```
db.query("SELECT owner FROM dog_names;")
    print(db.query_result)
    print(db.query_result[0])
    var o = db.query_result[0]["owner"]
    print(o)
    var o_str = "SELECT name FROM owners WHERE id = {int};"
    var o_form = o_str.format({"int": o})
    db.query(o_form)
    print(db.query_result)
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum. And you posted as an answer something that does not answer the question. I suggest you edit your question to add this, or alternatively you can write a new question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address this.